# Unit root test p-value in R

Tags: r

I am using the adfTest function in R to calculate a unit root test.

```
adfTest(my_data)@test$p.value
```

gives me a p-value equal to: 0.638768201337864

Does that mean I can reject the null hypothesis which means my data are non-stationary? The p-value should have been less than 0.05 so that my data would be stationary in a 95% significance level.

Is my interpretation correct or is it the other way around?

By the way, my sample is too small - only 10 observations. Could this be affecting the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In augmented Dickey–Fuller test (ADF) tests the null hypothesis that a unit root is present in a time series sample. Therefore, with `p-value =  0.639` you **cannot reject the null hypothesis** that your time-series is non-stationary.

[Nice reference for R users](https://fabian-kostadinov.github.io/2015/01/27/comparing-adf-test-functions-in-r/)

Comment: Agree, I will fix that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph my sample is too small - only 10 observations. Could this be affecting the results I get? How do I deal with that?

Comment: @adrCoder The way to deal with this is to perform a [power analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(statistics)#Software_for_power_and_sample_size_calculations). Unfortunately I do not know how to perform this for the ADF test. In general you can always fall back to empirical power analysis though (by simulating samples from the theoretical distribution, or by bootstrap sampling).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have never heard of that. I will check it out!